# Simple analog clock get slows then Error shows up with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.x

I have started to learn pygame and I code a simple analog clock.

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

white = 255, 255, 255
size = width, height = 480, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

minute_hand = pygame.image.load('minute_hand.png')
minute_hand_rect = minute_hand.get_rect()  

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    center = minute_hand_rect.center
    rotate = pygame.transform.rotate

    minute_hand = rotate(minute_hand, -1)
    minute_hand_rect = minute_hand.get_rect(center=center)

    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(minute_hand, minute_hand_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(100)
```

[image: This is my hand_minute]

But my hand_clock getting slower and slower for a while then stops to running and says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clock.py", line 21, in <module>
    minute_hand = rotate(minute_hand, -1)
pygame.error: Width or height is too large
```

Apparently I'm doing something so wrong but I couldn't figure what is wrong.

Comment: It's because when you rotate by increments other than 90 degrees it will enlarge your image size to hold the new rotated image

Comment: Increase the size of the screen so it is large enough for the image, or use a smaller image, because, as Racialz says, the rotations are increasing the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `minute_hand = rotate(minute_hand, -1)`

This is using the last frames image to generate the next, which means storing a whole load of transformation data each time it updates. It also gave me an 'Out of memory error' and as you'll notice causes the image to get distorted over time

The solution is to keep using the original image and rotate it more

Shown below:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

white = 255, 255, 255
size = width, height = 480, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

minute_hand = pygame.image.load('box4.jpg')
minute_hand_rect = minute_hand.get_rect()  

angle = 0

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    center = minute_hand_rect.center
    rotate = pygame.transform.rotate

    new_image = rotate(minute_hand, angle)
    new_image_rect = new.get_rect(center=center)

    angle -= 1
    if angle == -360:
        angle = 0

    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(new, new_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(100)
```

This takes an angle that changes every frame and applies it to the original

Hope this helps.